# DataTable Rowfilter syntax for filtering rows based on range

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datatable

So I am trying to filter out the rows where the column is named `gpa`.

Obviously I want to filter it based on a range. But seems like the syntax does not include `BETWEEN`. What's the alternative solution?

My code:

`t.DefaultView.RowFilter = "[gpa] BETWEEN " + filterGPAFrom.Text + " AND " + filterGPATo.Text;`

UPDATE:

I tried new code:
`t.DefaultView.RowFilter = "[gpa] > " + Convert.ToDouble(filterGPAFrom.Text) + " AND [gpa] <" + Convert.ToDouble(filterGPATo.Text);`

It works just fine but it seems having trouble filtering the result when the input is a whole number but in `double` form like `3.0` or `2.0`.

The data in `gpa` column are all `double`.

It will throw an error like this: `System.Data.EvaluateException: Cannot perform '>' operation on System.String and System.Int32.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try greater than and less than. So, `[gpa] > filterGPAFrom.Text AND [gpa] < filterGPATo.Text`. You might have to switch the greater than and less than symbol with actual words.